# How to get `browser-sync reload` to use https

Tags: node.js, command-line, browser-sync

I've a browser-sync instance serving my app, which uses bs-config.json and within that configuration file I specify https and a cert and key.   Later, I need to manually force a reload by calling `browser-sync reload`; however, this call results in a "socket hangup".  I believe this error occurs because browser-sync reload is posting to the default port and http.  I tried passing the same config to the reload call, but that doesn't change it.  I also tried using command line switches and specifying `https: true`, which doesn't work either.

How can a command-line call to browser-sync reload work when using non-default settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I recalled a way to work-around the problem and then found info and a proper solution:

**work-around**: `curl --silent -X POST https://localhost.test.com:3000/__browser_sync__?method=reload`

**bug-info**: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1235

**proper solution**: `browser-sync reload --url https://localhost.test.com:3000`